# Merging CSV files with batch file including filename in each line

Tags: batch-file, csv, merge

searched through previous question couldn't find any matching mine.

I need a batch file that would merge all CSV files in a folder matching a wildcard to a new merged CSV file and also in each merged line it would add the original file name at the end of each transferred string. I tried this commands that didn't work:

```
for /F "tokens=1* delims=" %%i in (^"SO_*.csv^") do @echo %%i,%%~ni >> MERGED.csv
```

it doesn't pick up lines, it just picks up "SO_*.csv" and also a file name of the first actual file, puts them into MERGED.csv and stops.

where have i gone wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are these carrets? To process lines in a file you need to use: `for /F "usebackq" %%i in ("SO_*.csv") ..` or `for /F  %%i in (SO_*.csv) ..`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@echo off
    break > merged.csv
    for %%f in (so_*.csv) do for /F "tokens=*" %%g in ('type "%%f"') do echo %%g,%%f >> merged.csv
```

Or for a faster approach

```
@echo off

    break > merged.csv
    for /F "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%f in ('findstr /R "." so_*.csv') do echo %%g,%%f >> merged.csv
```

Comment: worked as charm! thank you, i am just trying to understand the logic, as i understand you split it into two cycles, one cycle for each file separately and the cycle inside of it for each string in the file?

Comment: You are right. As you need to include the file name in each of the lines, each of the lines needs to be processed. And this needs to be done for each of the files. There is a faster approach using findstr over the complete file mask but this solution is similar to what you are trying. Anyway, will update answer with it.

Comment: `>> merged.csv echo %%g,%%f` <-- just a friendly nudge - putting the redirection first eliminates the need for spaces at the end of every line.

Comment: @foxidrive, or remove space from line `echo %%g,%%f>>merged.csv

Comment: That is a problem when the variable has a numeral at the end.  Try echoing 1 or 2 into a file that way.

Comment: @foxidrive, you are right. BUT, in this case, as the end of line is the name of a csv file, the probability of it having a numeral at end is low enough to keep that syntax. It is easier to read (just my opinion), and the first you see when reading the code is how the process works. Different sintaxes for different solutions to different problems.

Comment: I am suggesting this as a standard method into the future. Easier to read is subjective, and may be biased as what you are used to. If you adopt this more reliable method as your standard syntax it will also help newbies who read the code of answers, rather than them seeing an added space, or not realising what will happen with numerals and redirection.  I've been using this for the last decade at least, so all I'm saying is give it some thought.

Comment: @foxidrive, as said, you are right. And yes, i've also been using it, and yes, i take it into consideration, and yes, is subjective, and as said, just my opinion, and yes, i gave it some thought when writing and decided (subjective) to do it that way. And as said i wanted to keep the how it works at first sight, not trying to prevent every posible problem (and there are a lot more than those stated here), just to keep "more clear" (subjective) how it works.