# Merging CSV files with batch file including filename

Tags: csv, batch-file, merge

I want to merge CSV files with batch file including filename in each line.
I found this post about this:

[Merging CSV files with batch file including filename in each line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808560/merging-csv-files-with-batch-file-including-filename-in-each-line)

But it is not working for me, because my CSV files have not always the same amount of columns (sometimes the last one is missing).
So if I split the merged CSV file by comma, the filename is not in the same column.

So my question: is it possible to set the name at the beginning of each transferred string?

Below my batch file:

```
@echo off
break > merged.csv
for %%f in (*.csv) do for /F "tokens=*" %%g in ('type "%%f"') do echo %%g,%%f >> merged2.csv

findstr /v UID merged2.csv  > merged2_without_header.csv
```

It would be great, if somebody could help me (I am not a coder:-) )

Best,
Peter

Comment: Reverse %%g and %%f in your echo command.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works! Two more questions: 1.) Can I write the filename in a sepearte column? Because now are the titelname and first column comma-sepaerted in the same column. 2.) It would be great if I could use the batch file also for xlsx Files. But If i replace *.csv it does not work.

Comment: I don't see how it's possible for the title name and the first column data to be in the same column if they've been separated by a comma and the file data is delimited by commas. Is this one of those weird CSVs that doesn't actually use **c**ommas to **s**eparate **v**alues?

Comment: The  file date is delimited by TAB (Tab-separated values).

Comment: Ah. Then you're going to want to change your echo statement to `%%f<TAB>%%g`, where <TAB> is an actual tab.

Comment: Oh sorry. The file date is delimited by comma (comma-seperated values). But If i open the merged CSV, the CSV does not use commas to separate values. They are alreday seperated by Tab. Only the first column with the filename is using the comma.